# How to return result based on a string found on a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, arraylist

I'm trying to return all data from my excel sheet from the column TOURNAMENT that has the string FIFA. I keep getting no results back and am not sure how to fix this. Below is a sample of data from my excel. Any insight would be helpful thank you

My excel:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

filename = ("results.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(filename)


#convert to datetime format
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y/%M/%D')

#Which country has scored the most goals in FIFA events (qualifiers, cups, etc.) since 2010?
#To get the most goals by sum
df['total_score'] = df['home_score'] + df['away_score']  

#Not sure how to check all data with the string "FIFA" in the column "Tournament" 
sub_df = df[(df['date'].dt.year >= 2010)]

if "FIFA" in df['tournament']:
  sub_df2 = sub_df[sub_df['total_score'] == sub_df['total_score'].max()]  
  print(sub_df2)
else:
  print("no results")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Series.str.contains` to check if a substring exists in the value, then use the masking to get only such occurrences:

```py
>>> df[df['tournament'].str.contains('FIFA')]
```

Comment: how would I use that in an IF condition? thanks